# Redis key name doesn't match name define in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm using redis to cache some data. The key name i set in laravel is 'users' and I think it works fine, but when i checked the redis-cli for **GET USERS** it returns nil. After monitoring the redis cli and running the app, the key name was saved as 'laravel_database_users' and not as 'users'. Why? thanks.

[image: Redis monitor]

**Laravel Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    if(Redis::exists('users')) {
        $users = json_decode(Redis::get('users'));
    }else{
        $users = User::all();   
        Redis::set('users',$users);
    }   
    return view('home',compact('users'));
}
```

Comment: The cache prefix is set in [`config/cache.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/cache.php)

Comment: The wording came out bad and mixed the terms meant collisions :) my bad